# puppet: symlinks for directories in yet-to-be-installed packages

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet

We currently use puppet 3.8.7 to provision a large number of AWS EC2 instances.

Since these machines have small and slow root volumes, we symlink certain directories from e.g. /var to /mnt.

This leads to manifests riddles with segments like this:

```
group { 'postgres':
  ensure  => present,
  system  => true,
}

user { 'postgres':
  ensure  => present,
  comment => 'PostgreSQL administrator',
  gid     => 'postgres',
  home    => '/var/lib/postgresql',
  require => Group['postgres'],
}

file { '/mnt/postgresql':
  ensure  => directory,
  owner   => 'postgres',
  group   => 'postgres',
  mode    => '0755',
  require => User['postgres'],
}

file { '/var/lib/postgresql':
  ensure  => link,
  target  => '/mnt/postgresql',
  require => File['/mnt/postgresql'],
  before  => Class['dbserver'],
}
```

This is

1. ugly
2. overly verbose

   and
3. error prone if an implicit dependency (e.g. on postgresql-client) creates the directory before the `file` statement is evaluated.

So I'm wondering, how do other people tackle this?

Is there a better way to ensure that

- such symlinks *always* get created before the package containing the directory gets installed

but

- they *only* get created if a package containing the directory *is going to be* installed?

Comment: Read more about Puppet notify.

Comment: I'm afraid I am not sure how `notify` would help here.
`notify` indicates to another resource that something has changed and it should account for that.
If in this case, the package is already installed (and thus can be notified), it is too late for the link to be placed.

Answer (score 1):

The puppet files are reflecting your system configuration, and are thus a bit ugly. I suggest one of the following solutions:

- Restructuring your system configuration might help a bit. Do not mount your device to /mnt/postgres, but to /var/lib/postgresql, or maybe use a `/var` partition.
- If your only problem is postgres being installed before your symlink creation, this is easy: Enforce creation of the symlink before the postgres installation.

  ```
  package { 'postgresql':
    ensure  => installed,
    require => File['/var/lib/postgresql'],
  }
  ```

  If you want to fix systems where your problem already persists, I recommend implementing a fixing `exec` statement, similar to this:

  ```
  exec { '/usr/local/bin/fix_postgres_installation.sh':
    user   => 'root,
    onlyif => 'test -d /var/lib/postgresql',
    before => File['/var/lib/postgresql'],
  }
  ```

  The script could possibly shutdown the postgres, sync the data to `/mnt/postgres`, delete `/var/lib/postgres`.
- If you simply want to force director deletion for the file resource, you can use the `force` option, as described in the [Puppet documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#file-attribute-force)
- Change the data directories of your applications. Most applications allow this. For Postgres, the settign `data_directory()` should help you, also see the [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://a).

Comment: The real problem is that EC2 instances provide a very poor root volume with space and speed only available on the local instance storage mounted to /mnt.
Mounting this under /var would not work since the base image already contains files there and not all instances we use the image on will have local storage at all.
What I am looking for is a more generic way to define directories that should be symlinks if they exist.

Comment: I added some other options reflecting this.